Difference between BlocProvider.of and context.read for adding events in the flutter bloc
We can add a event in flutter bloc by two ways
BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context).add(const GetCartList());

and
 context.read<CartBloc>().add(const GetCartList());

So what is basic difference between two ways?


context.read() looks up the closest ancestor instance of type T and is functionally equivalent to BlocProvider.of(context)

Both code snippets are actually the same. context.read is an extension of BuildContext. Under the hood, it does the same as BlocProvider.of(context).
More info on context.read.

Can you provide more information  please. I didn't get your point

Both code snippet do the same. It's a design choice which you prefer.
